# Hypersurface of Schwarzschild spacetime on which induced metric is flat

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature

I have to present an exercise in class and want to make sure that my approach and understanding of the problem is correct.

> Let $\Sigma$ be the hypersurface in Schwarzschild spacetime (metric $g$) defined by $\big( t,r,\theta,\phi \big) = \big( f(r),r,\theta,\phi \big)$. Find $f$ such that the metric $h$ induced on $\Sigma$ is flat.

Now, my approach is to calculate the metric $h$ induced on $\Sigma$ by replacing $dt = df$ within the metric $g = -a(r) \, dt^2 + 1/a(r) \, dr^2 + r^2 \, d\Omega^2$. After that, I calculate the Christoffel symbols in order to finally calculate the Riemann curvature tensor. If the Riemann curvature tensor vanishes, then the metric is considered flat. I therefore have to solve the differential equation for $f(r)$, obtained by calculating the Riemann curvature tensor and assuming it to vanish.

Is this approach/idea correct? The calculations to obtain the Riemann curvature tensor is quite lengthy I suppose, and it will contain some third-degree derivative of $f$. Is there another (easier) way to show flatness of a metric?

Comment: As another idea, compute the induced metric, then perform a coordinate transformation to put in the form of a flat metric (for instance in spherical coordinates). Then there should end up being some condition on $f$ so that this transformation is possible, which hopefully can be solved. It's not guaranteed to be tractable and less systematic than computing the Riemann tensor -- there's a free choice in terms of what form of the flat metric you want to end up in after the coordinate transformation and the problem may only be solvable for some choices. But, if it works, it'll be less algebra.

Comment: The idea behind the exercise is that you just look at the induced metric and see if it resembles a flat metric that you already know. No curvature calculations necessary.

Comment: if $~t=f(r)~$ hence $~ dt=\frac{df}{dr}\,dr = f'(r)\,dr~$ ? you wrote $~dt=df $

Comment: To Andrew and Javier: Although I find Andrews approach conceptually interesting, I will try to solve this as Javier suggested because it seems to be less effort. Thank you both for the input. I will post my solution here as soon as I am done. | To Eli: yes, you are correct, I assumed this implication was obvious.

Comment: @Javier I updated my question to include my attempt to apply your suggestion. Is there some hint you can give me?

Comment: @Octavius Actually what I meant is exactly what Javier said, so you also implemented what I had in mind :) Also it looks like wolfram alpha can integrate your function exactly in terms of an inverse tanh function: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sqrt%28+%282m%2Fr%29+%2F+%281-2m%2Fr%29%5E2+%29+dr

Comment: the integral is $f(r)=-2\,\sqrt {ar}+a \left( \ln  \left( \sqrt {ar}+a \right) -\ln  \left( 
\sqrt {ar}-a \right)  \right) +c
~$ where a=2m

Comment: To Andrew: Oh, I misunderstood your approach at first, sorry. | To All: Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Octavius No worries, I was a bit overly general / complicated in how I described things. It's a lot harder to communicate in an internet comment box than in front of a blackboard. Glad it seems to have worked out. You can write up your own answer and accept it, if you want, might be useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by ANDREW, I will write up the answer to the question here myself.

Given the hypersurface $\Sigma = \{ t = f(r) \}$, the induced metric is obtained by replacing $dt = df$ within the expression for the Schwarzschild metric $g$. The induced metric turns out to be

$$h \enspace = \enspace \Big[ \tfrac{1}{a(r)} - a(r) \, \big( \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} \big)^2 \Big] \, dr^2 + r^2 \, d\Omega^2$$

Following  ANDREW's and JAVIER's proposal, I now identify the induced metric with some flat metric I already know. Since I am using spherical coordinates, the Euclidean metric in spherical coordinates volunteers for such an approach. In order for the induced metric to coincide with the Euclidean metric in spherical coordinates, the property

$$ \Big[ \tfrac{1}{a(r)} - a(r) \, \big( \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial r} \big)^2 \Big] \enspace = \enspace 1$$

must hold. This leads to

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \enspace = \enspace \sqrt{\frac{1-a(r)}{a^2(r)}} \enspace = \enspace \sqrt{\frac{\tfrac{2m}{r}}{\big(1-\tfrac{2m}{r} \big)^2}} \quad ,$$

where $a(r) = 1 - \tfrac{2m}{r}$. The solution for this integral is

$$ f \enspace = \enspace 2m \cdot \bigg( 2\sqrt{\tfrac{r}{2m}} + \ln \Big( \big| 1 - \sqrt{\tfrac{r}{2m}} \big| \Big) - \ln \Big( 1 + \sqrt{\tfrac{r}{2m}} \Big) \bigg)$$

up to some constant. The hypersurface is now the set of points with coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi) = (f(r), r, \theta, \phi)$, where $f$ is the above function.